# Groovy - Looping through a JSON object and populating the response with the values as a single row

Tags: groovy

I am have a JSON Object like this

```
{   
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "SpotId": 4,
    "**Academic**": [{
        "id": 291938,
        "type": email,
        "**Subjects**": {
            "id": 1234,
            "name": "English",
            "**Exams**": {
                   . . . 
                "**Marks**": {
                      . . . 
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

SO basically I am trying to iterate thru this object and build a spreadsheet with all the values like

| User | UserID | Academic | Exam | Subject | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Email | MidTerm | English | 90 |
| 1 | 1 | Communication | MidTerm | English | 90 |

So for this I am using a each loop like:

```
jsonObject. each { first ->
  first.academic?.each { second ->
     second.exam?.each { third ->
        third.subject?.each { fourth ->
           fourth.mark?.each { fifth ->
              response.add(
                     ['user': first.user],
                     ['user': first.userID],
                     ['user': second .academic],
                     ['user': third .exam],
                     ['user': fourth .subject],
                     ['user': fifth .mark],
                     ['user': fifth .grade],

              )
```

The issue I am facing is its not looping thru all the rows in the json properly... I dont see the first.user and first.userID in the excel..it is always empty.

But when i move the below piece

```
 response.add(
      ['user': first.user],
      ['user': first.userID]
)
```

to the first each loop - I see the values:

```
  jsonObject. each { first ->
response.add(
            ['user': first.user],
            ['user': first.userID])**
      first.academic?.each { second ->
         second.exam?.each { third ->
            third.subject?.each { fourth ->
               fourth.mark?.each { fifth ->
                  response.add(
                         ['user': first.user],
                         ['user': first.userID],
                         ['user': second .academic],
                         ['user': third .exam],
                         ['user': fourth .subject],
                         ['user': fifth .mark],
                         ['user': fifth .grade],
    
                  )
```

But the excel is messing up.

Is there a way i can loop thru each of those and add those fields to the response.
Need to loop thru each section and add to response (as same row) if value exists if not just store the response and move to next one so I can read and display them in excel(that portion of code is working just fine). I need a solution to populate the response appropriately with all these value.

Any help on this will be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `response`? "See values", "is messing up" - **what** values? Please add the errenous and the expected output.

Comment: def response = []
thats the list which will be set to returning object

Comment: All i need to know is how can i loop thru each of those sections and add values if exists else break at a point where it does not have any values and move to next user

Comment: If response is a a list, then `.add` on it with multiple arguments will throw.

Comment: Can you give a minimal, but complete input example, and a complete output you'd expect from it?  Showing what you mean by "_break at a point_"?